# Vue-Bootstrap doesn't work with Django. How can I start with it correctly?

Tags: javascript, django, vue.js, bootstrap-4

I'm really new to VueJS. I'm trying to use vue-bootstrap instead of usual bootstrap (including jquery).

But it doesn't work at all even though there's no error. All files are loaded.

`base.html`

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.css"/>
</head>
<body>

{% block content %}
{% endblock content %}

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.21/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/babel-polyfill@latest/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>
</body>
```

and I copied this from the example of vue-bootstrap doc
https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/navbar/

`index.html`

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<b-navbar toggleable="md" type="dark" variant="info">

  <b-navbar-toggle target="nav_collapse"></b-navbar-toggle>

  <b-navbar-brand href="#">NavBar</b-navbar-brand>

  <b-collapse is-nav id="nav_collapse">

<b-navbar-nav>
  <b-nav-item href="#">Link</b-nav-item>
  <b-nav-item href="#" disabled>Disabled</b-nav-item>
</b-navbar-nav>

<!-- Right aligned nav items -->
<b-navbar-nav class="ml-auto">

  <b-nav-form>
    <b-form-input size="sm" class="mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search"/>
    <b-button size="sm" class="my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</b-button>
  </b-nav-form>

  <b-nav-item-dropdown text="Lang" right>
    <b-dropdown-item href="#">EN</b-dropdown-item>
    <b-dropdown-item href="#">ES</b-dropdown-item>
    <b-dropdown-item href="#">RU</b-dropdown-item>
    <b-dropdown-item href="#">FA</b-dropdown-item>
  </b-nav-item-dropdown>

  <b-nav-item-dropdown right>
    <!-- Using button-content slot -->
    <template slot="button-content">
      <em>User</em>
    </template>
    <b-dropdown-item href="#">Profile</b-dropdown-item>
    <b-dropdown-item href="#">Signout</b-dropdown-item>
  </b-nav-item-dropdown>
    </b-navbar-nav>

  </b-collapse>
</b-navbar>

{% endblock content %}
```

But it shows like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUWJl.png)

What am I wrong with it?

Comment: are you maybe missing a 'https:' in front of your src="... ?

Comment: But according to the doc, this way is correct. https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/

Comment: I see. Seems odd. Maybe try it anyway, just for fun.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not create a Vue instance and that's why it's not working.

```
<script>
  new Vue({ el: '#app' });
</script>
```

> Every Vue application starts by creating a new Vue instance with the
> Vue function. See docs for [more](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html).

Here's the working implementation.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link
      type="text/css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    <link
      type="text/css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.css"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
   
    <div id="app">
        <b-navbar toggleable="md" type="dark" variant="info">

            <b-navbar-toggle target="nav_collapse"></b-navbar-toggle>
          
            <b-navbar-brand href="#">NavBar</b-navbar-brand>
          
            <b-collapse is-nav id="nav_collapse">
          
          <b-navbar-nav>
            <b-nav-item href="#">Link</b-nav-item>
            <b-nav-item href="#" disabled>Disabled</b-nav-item>
          </b-navbar-nav>
          
          <!-- Right aligned nav items -->
          <b-navbar-nav class="ml-auto">
          
            <b-nav-form>
              <b-form-input size="sm" class="mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search"/>
              <b-button size="sm" class="my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</b-button>
            </b-nav-form>
          
            <b-nav-item-dropdown text="Lang" right>
              <b-dropdown-item href="#">EN</b-dropdown-item>
              <b-dropdown-item href="#">ES</b-dropdown-item>
              <b-dropdown-item href="#">RU</b-dropdown-item>
              <b-dropdown-item href="#">FA</b-dropdown-item>
            </b-nav-item-dropdown>
          
            <b-nav-item-dropdown right>
              <!-- Using button-content slot -->
              <template slot="button-content">
                <em>User</em>
              </template>
              <b-dropdown-item href="#">Profile</b-dropdown-item>
              <b-dropdown-item href="#">Signout</b-dropdown-item>
            </b-nav-item-dropdown>
              </b-navbar-nav>
          
            </b-collapse>
          </b-navbar>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.21/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="//unpkg.com/babel-polyfill@latest/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>

    <script>
      new Vue({ el: '#app' });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

*Just a side note, using protocol-relative URLs didn't work on my local so I have to put `https` in front of my imported scripts and stylesheets.*

Comment: No worries. You're new to Vue, we all make mistakes.